# Axios.get call for years as value

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, get, axios

I am trying to get a json file from server. Endpoint has a year parameter with the current year number as value like so: ?year=2019. I also need to get a year before that and next year. So if someone enters data in the backend for 2018, 2019 or 2020 I should be able to retrieve it. The problem is that I cannot hard code the years since next year I would need 2019, 2020 and 2021 and so on :)

I currently have pretty basic setup but have tried all sorts of things which of course don't work.

```
data() {
 return {
  year:[]
 }
},

computed: {
 axiosParams(){
  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('year', this.year);
  return params;
 }
},

getYears: function() {
    axios.get('myurl',{
     params : this.axiosParams
    }
    }).then((response) => {
      this.year = response.data;
    })
}
```

If I hardcode it like year: '2019' in the data, everything works ok. I am new to Vue and Axios so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a little javascript magic to get this year or an array of the years you want like so:

```
  year() {
      var now = new Date()
      var nowy = now.getFullYear()

      return nowy
    },
```

This will return `2019`

```
  years() {
      var yearsArray = []
      var now = new Date()
      for (let i = -1; i < 2; i++) {
        var nowy = now.getFullYear() + i
        yearsArray.push(nowy)
      }
      return yearsArray
    },
```

This will return an array like this: `[2018, 2019, 2020]`

Then it's up to how you use that, you can send either this year or an array to your api.

Comment: Andrew, thank you so much! I wasn't expecting an answer that quickly :) So years array returns all the years in one link. Would you have any idea on how should I prefill all three years into a drop down and fire a get call on each individual year that is selected? Let say I pick 2020, i get ?year=2020. If I pick 2019 I get ?year=2019. Thank you!

Comment: @mx1517 you could have a select input where the options are iterated in a `v-for="year in years"` and trigger a method that makes your api call. You'd need a v-model to bind the year. This is pretty easy especially if you're using a material framework like vuetify. If you want a more detailed answer you should ask a new question.

Comment: I did ask another one so if you have time please take a look at it since I am having issues with setting new year and an id. I get setter error. Thank you!